# FFT calculation suitable, Wav File, Java

Tags: fft, audio, wave, java

If I have a wav file with this characteristics:

- 16bits (2 Bytes per Sample)
- 32000 Sampling Rate
- 60 Seconds
- 2 Channels

then I have:

```
Samples Per Channel: 32000*60 = 1920000
Samples Per File: 32000*60*2 = 3840000
Bytes Per File: 32000*60*2*2 = 7680000
```

It's a huge file!

If I change my file Characteristics to:

- 8bits (1 Byte per Sample)
- 8000 Sampling Rate
- 60 Seconds
- 1 Channel

then I have:

```
Samples Per Channel: 8000*60 = 480000
Samples Per File: 8000*60*1 = 480000
Bytes Per File: 8000*60*1*1 = 480000
```

If my FFT 2^12 = 4096 or 2^16 = 65536

**Do I need to calculate the FFT 480000 times?**

**Does each how many samples I need to calculate the FFT?**  (480000 - 65536 = **414464?**)

what is the suitable calculus?

How to do to show the spectrum?

Answer (score 1):

To show only one spectrum then FFT of the whole sample could be done.But for better result you could take a window and take FFT. For taking windows of 4096 with 50% overlap then it is equivalent to doing FFT
no of times
$$
\frac{480000}{4096*0.5}
$$
times that is equivalent to
$$
\frac{Total\hspace{1mm} sample\hspace{1mm} length}{(window \hspace{1mm}length)*(amount\hspace{1mm} of\hspace{1mm} overlap)}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have in account! this mean that I need perform 235 FFT's.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how the spectrum is changing over time, which is what it sounds like you want to do, then don't do it for every sample - it's too much information and too much calculation.

A rule of thumb I use is to calculate the Fourier Transform every 0.05 seconds, since this is roughly the human ear's temporal resolution. In your case, at a sampling frequency of 8kHz, that's a FT every 400 samples.

You also don't need to use the entire 60 seconds of data for each FT. A common technique here is to do a [short-time FT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) - i.e. each point in time that you want to calculate the spectrum for you use a data 'window' of a certain sample size (e.g. 4096 samples). Also consider multiplying each 'window' of data by a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to reduce spectral leakage.

Comment: Thank you, Where you obtain the rule "every 0.05 seconds, since this is roughly the human ear's temporal resolution." have you a link o greater information...